# Convert timestamp to a specified timezone offset

Tags: timezone, offset

How can I convert a long timestamp, e.g. `2556072000000L`, to a String in a specified timezone offset, e.g. `+08:30`? I looked into Joda methods but didn't find a solution.
Similarly, how can I convert a String timestamp, e.g. `2050-12-31T04:00:00Z`, to a String in a specified timezone offset, e.g. `+08:30`?
`2050-12-31T12:30:00+08:30` in the specified offset is expected.

Parsing `+08:30` into three parts: `+`, hour offset (`8`) and minute offset (`30`), add the offset to the `timestamp` or `dateTime` could be a solution. However, I'm wondering whether there's already a solution so that I needn't reinvent wheels?

```
/*
 * timestamp: 2556072000000L (2050-12-31T04:00:00Z)
 * offset: +08:30
 * return: 2050-12-31T12:30:00+08:30
 */
String toOffset(long timestamp, String offset);

/*
 * dateTime: 2050-12-31T04:00:00Z
 * offset: +08:30
 * return: 2050-12-31T12:30:00+08:30
 */
String toOffset(String dateTime, String offset);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-zone-offset), I got the answer to my question. Here it is:

```
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

/*
 * timestamp: 2556072000000L (2050-12-31T04:00:00Z)
 * offset: +08:30
 * return: 2050-12-31T12:30:00+08:30
 */
public String toOffset(long timestamp, String offset); { // +08:30
        DateTime time = new DateTime(timestamp + getOffsetMillis(offset));
        time = time.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID(DateTimeZone.UTC.getID())); // 2050-12-31T12:30:00Z
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        String dateStr = time.toString(formatter);  // 2050-12-31T12:30:00
        return dateStr + offset; // 2050-12-31T12:30:00+08:30
}

public long getOffsetMillis(String offset) { // +08:30
    ZoneOffset zoneOffSet = ZoneOffset.of(offset);
    return zoneOffSet.getTotalSeconds() * 1000; // (8 * 60 * 60 + 30 * 60) * 1000
}
```

Please note that the timezone offset must be in the inclusive range of [-18:00, +18:00]. Below is quoted from [JDK document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html)

> In 2008, time-zone offsets around the world extended from -12:00 to
> +14:00. To prevent any problems with that range being extended, yet still provide validation, the range of offsets is restricted to -18:00
> to 18:00 inclusive.

If you look at the Joda timezone [table](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/timezones.html), you will find that offsets for all the timezones are in the range of [-12:00, +14:00].